# How to make a thread wait until other threads are completed

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a function funcA() that is called by a thread. This function funcA() calls multiple functions, all which run on other parallel threads. I want my 1st thread that called funcA() to wait until all these threads have completed their work and then move to the next line for further execution.

eg Thread1 -> funcA();

```
funcA()
{
    funcBackground();   

    //Once the above method's threads have completed their work
    doSomeOtherWork(); 
}

funcBackground()
{
    Thread2 -> doJob1();
    Thread3 -> doJob2();
    Thread4 -> doJob3();
    .
    .
    .
//All the above threads have completed their work
}
```

How can I achieve this?
I know you might be thinking if I want to run all in a single thread then why am I using multiple threads in funcBackground(). The point is that my funcBackground() is called from multiple places. But I want this single thread execution only in one place in the application.

Comment: how about await keyword? async await im use that in kotlin

Comment: I am not in kotlin. Are there any suggestions for Java based rxjava for Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can create all the threads (Thread2, thread3....) implementing `callables` which will return Futures.

and don't come out of the `funcBackground` until all threads are completed like below.

```
    while(!future2.isDone());
    while(!future3.isDone());
    while(!future4.isDone());
```

Or you can use

`future2.get()` as this is also blocking.

Comment: Your advice is up-side down. The OP should use `future2.get()` unless there is a good reason to busy wait.